# Explain the following Java/Groovy behavior

Tags: java, groovy, character-encoding

Code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("测试");
    }
}
```

**Scenario 1:**
Filename: *Main.groovy*
Run as: Groovy Script

Output:
`æµ‹è¯•`

**Scenario 2:**
Filename: *Main.groovy*
Run as: Java Application

Output: 
`??`

**Scenario 3:**
Filename: *Main.java*
Run as: Java Application

Output: `测试`

*EDIT 1*

**Environment**
 - Eclipse 4.2.1
 - Groovy 2.0.6
 - JDK 8u112

Comment: What does "Run as: Groovy Script" and "Run as: Java Application" mean? What command-line do you use for that? Or is it an IDE function? Then don't you think it would be appropriate to tell us *which* IDE?

Comment: What character encoding did you use when saving the `.java`/`.groovy` source file? Did you tell your compiler? What character encoding are you using where running the code? What happens if you change source code to `System.out.println("\u6D4B\u8BD5")`?

Comment: Everything works fine with .java with UTF-8 encoding. But, when I try to run .groovy script with UTF-8 and Cp1252 encoding, I get  `æµ‹è¯•`.

Comment: And for `System.out.println("\u6D4B\u8BD5")` I get `??` (when I run as .groovy script, no matter what encoding the file has)

Comment: Every source can have different code-page association, or default to his environment.  I work in Poland and have similar problem from time to time. I guess it has nothing to java-groovy integration

Comment: @JacekCz What do you mean by code-page association?

Comment: I work with java source from Eclipse. And Eclipse project can have default UTF-8 (variable 8/16 bit/characters from Polish perspective, or 1250 (Microsoft developed code page for Poland, single byte characters). So association = eclipse project default. I don't know in different editors / IDE. Interesting is change of length of strings.

Comment: Writing national strings in programming language sources is generally bad pattern (should be used \n unicode numbers) but is convenient
. Theory is theory, practice is practice. Every programmer who use such coding must resolve problems from time to time. Look at sources  with good programmers editor (Scite from scinitlla.org?) and test changing code page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Make sure source and output encodings are all configured to handle your character set, e.g. all set to `UTF-8`.

---

Either change your `print` statement to this:

```
System.out.println("\u6D4B\u8BD5");
```

or make sure Eclipse knows the encoding of the source file.

Best thing to do, is to change Eclipse workspace to save files in UTF-8.[image]

Alternatively, change Eclipse project to save files in UTF-8.
[image]

Each source file in Eclipse can also have different encoding, so check that too, but it's best if you don't use that, because compiling outside Eclipse will then be very complex.
[image]

When you then choose to run your program, whether as "Java Application" or as "Groovy Script", Eclipse will create a "Run Configuration" object. You can see them by selecting the `Run` > `Run Configurations...` pull-down menu.

The Run Configuration has a "Common" tab. Make sure it's configured to display output in UTF-8.
[image]

When that is all done, your code will run fine.
[image]

Note that I'm in the USA, so my default encoding is `cp1252`, as can be seen in the images, but I can still do those characters just fine, when I configure Eclipse to do `UTF-8`.

The above was done on:
- Eclipse 4.5.1 (Mars.1)
- Groovy 2.3.10
- Java 1.8.0_91
- Windows 7 Pro SP1

Answer (score 1):

The said behavior seemed to be specific to `windows` platform.

Please make sure the eclipse settings are choose right Text file encoding at the project level using `project -> right click -> configure`. i.e., Change in this case to `UTF-8` as shown in the below image.

You can also see the right out on the right hand side when `Main.groovy` is executed as `groovy script`.
Of course, you would see the correct result even if you run `Main.groovy` as *Java application* as well.

[image]

Hope this is helpful.